# index a text file (lines with different size) in c++

Tags: c++, text, indexing, seek

I have to extract information from a text file.
In the text file there is a list of strings.
This is an example of a string: AAA101;2015-01-01 00:00:00;0.784
The value after the last ; is a non integer value, which changes from line to line, so every line has different lenght of characters.

I want to map all of these lines into a structured vector as I can access to a specific line anytime I need without scan the whole file again.

I did some research and I found some threads about a command called, which permit me to reach a specific line of a text file but I read it only works if any line has the same characters lenght of the others.

I was thinking about converting all the lines in the file in a proper format in order to be able to map that file as I want but I hope there is a better and quick way

Comment: It's not clear what your are asking.

Comment: append extra zeros at the end of the last field "value" . Be care full about the excpetions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `TStringList*`. It creates a list of AnsiStrings. Then each AnsiString can be accessed via `->operator [](numberOfTheLine)`.